# How to get all data from row wise from a resultset in jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table which is showing one row at a time, i.e in the first iteration it will give one row information and 2nd iteration and so on. Now I want to get all the  row data in result set. How I can do that??

This is the structure of my table:

```
 name   s  e  p f
 Allan  2  3  8 9
```

I am doing:

```
rsServeResource6 = st.executeQuery(sqlForIndividualMileStone);
while(rsServeResource6.next()){

    if(rsServeResource6.getString(2)!=null){                                
        engageActual = Integer.parseInt(rsServeResource6.getString(2));
        System.out.println("Results :"+engageActual);
    }else if(rsServeResource6.getString(3)!=null){
        qualificationActual = Integer.parseInt(rsServeResource6.getString(3));
        System.out.println("Results :"+qualificationActual);
    }else if(rsServeResource6.getString(4)!=null){
        isSubmissionActual =  Integer.parseInt(rsServeResource6.getString(4));
        System.out.println("Results :"+isSubmissionActual);
    }else if(rsServeResource6.getString(5)!=null){
        presentActual = Integer.parseInt(rsServeResource6.getString(5));
        System.out.println("Results :"+presentActual);
    }else if(rsServeResource6.getString(6)!=null){
        interviewActual = Integer.parseInt(rsServeResource6.getString(6)); 
        System.out.println("Results :"+interviewActual);
    }
}
```

like that.

How can I achieve that ??

Comment: and what you think your **ResultSet** currently contains , when you execute `st.executeQuery()`

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: i want to achieve value of  s in engageActual,value of  e in qualificationActual so on

Comment: @lucifer: But that is exactly what happens... I think we need more information what you want to do

Comment: but in my code i am getting column wise  values  i.e i am getting value of s  for allan and then value of  s for another person in the next iteration

Comment: Because u are using `else if` use `if`

Comment: @Nitin: that's it. Having the answer i now understand the problem :)

Comment: I'll put that as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if` instead of using `else if` when fetching results